# undefined local variable or method error using delegate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ihave some code and i'm using delegate function this way:

I'm using Ruby On rails '5.2.1' and ruby '2.5.3'

```rb
#Owner model
class Owner < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :expenses
  delegate :list_of_this_month, to: :expense, prefix: true
end
```

```rb
#Expense model
class Expense < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner

  def list_of_this_month
    select { |e| e.day_month == DateTime.current.strftime('%Y-m') }
  end

  def day_month
    date.strftime('%Y-m')
  end
end
```

```rb
#Expenses Controller
class ExpensesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @expenses = current_owner.expense_list_of_this_month
  end
end
```

In the view when i call

```html
  #{current_owner.expense_quantity_of_this_month}
```

Instead of the list of the current month and year expenses of the logged Owner, I'm getting this error:

--> undefined local variable or method `expense' for # Did you mean? expenses expenses=

So, how this error can be fixed?

Comment: Indeed, there's no method `expense` on Owner.

Comment: There's no 'expense', owners have expenses, plural--just like the error message says.

Comment: I changed for plural, now i'm getting this error:

undefined method `list_of_this_month' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

Comment: @NomadCoder87: that's to be expected too. A collection of expenses doesn't have this method. Individual expenses do (but its definition suggests that it  _should_ be a class method or a scope).

Comment: @NomadCoder87: you forgot to ask a question, btw.

Comment: Solved adding converting the class method in an instance method: 
self.def list_of_this_month
    select { |e| e.day_month == DateTime.current.strftime('%Y-m') }
  end

Comment: @sergio-tulentsev well i just want to error that i specified disapear, it obvious, thanks for the Help Sergio was very usefull, really thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestions, I changed "expense" for "expenses" and convert the class method in instance method

```rb
def self.list_of_this_month
  select { |e| e.day_month == DateTime.current.strftime('%Y-m') }
end
```